# Outline application with feature to toggle number of levels deep shown?

Tags: documentation, outline

I was debating between superuser and personal productivity for this question, if there is a better site for this question please move it!

I'm looking for an application for writing up outlines that has a feature allowing me to select how many levels deep are actually displayed. For example, if the actual outline is like this:

```
I. First level
 A. Second level
   1. Third level
     a. Fourth level
   2. Third level
 B. Second level
   1. Third level
```

I am looking for a software that has an option to only show for example "2" levels deep, and the result would be this:

```
I. First level
  A. Second level
  B. Second level
```

Of course it would keep the other levels and just hide that information until I change the level setting. Does anybody know of such an application? In particular if there is a way to do this with Google Docs that would be ideal.

Comment: Microsoft Word actually has a similar mode, although it is fairly simple in features.

Comment: I know Word has a numbering feature, but I can't figure out a way to do what I'm asking above? (hide some levels, but be able to restore them later). Any ideas?

Comment: I didn't mean the numbering feature, but rather the "View -> Outline" document view (which is actually intended for arranging document headings and subheadings).

Comment: Okay so I see that feature, but how would I specify how many levels deep of the outline are shown?

Comment: Word 2007 has a dropdown list in the Outline tab, limited to 9 levels.